# Change the color of the selected page number in the gridview paging footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

Gridview , Paging numbers.

When you select the number page in the footer of the gridview it will underline the selected number .

- Is there any way of changing the color of the selected number ?

Thank you

Comment: Post us your code ,we can help you better.

Comment: hmm .. you're asking me for code , code for what? I don't know how to change the color of the selected paging number..

Comment: possible duplicate of [GridView : Selected page button (number) style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354038/gridview-selected-page-button-number-style)

Comment: @Jax I meant the markup.Anyway you can always apply CssClass to the pagination and then style accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see that pagination class assigned `CssClass="pagination"`

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagination" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
 VerticalAlign="Middle"/>
```

---

```
.pagination .current {
    background: #26B;
    color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #AAE;
}
```

Comment: hm I did that and it didn't worked .  <title>Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .pagination .current {
    background: #26B;
    color: #800000;
    border: solid 1px #AAE; }
    </style>

Answer (score 5):

solved.........You can use a CSS class to do this: here is a sample.

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .pager span { color:#009900;font-weight:bold; font-size:16pt; }
  </style>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  PageSize="5  >
<PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1092990.aspx?Highlight+current+page+on+gridview+pager